# Event change com ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Preciso que um campo, ao ser definido um valor x, renderize outros dois campos. Com meu método atual, só consigo renderizar um único campo. Como faço para um selecOnMenu renderizar mais de um campo?

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="regional" styleClass="form-control bf-no-message bf-required"
value="#{relatorioPendenciaDocumentoBean.filtro.regional}" converter="entityConverter">
<f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel=""/>
<f:selectItems value="#{relatorioPendenciaDocumentoBean.regionais}" var="re" itemValue="#{re}" itemLabel="#{re.label}" />
<f:ajax event="change" render="campi" listener="#{relatorioPendenciaDocumentoBean.findCampusList}" />
```

Neste ajax, preciso que ele renderize o campo "curso", assim como o "campi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu não sei exatamente qual tecnologia você está utilizando, vou compartilhar uma solução que adotei usando apenas ajax.

$('idElemento').change(function (){

```
var valor = $( this ).val();
if(valor == valorASerComparado){

  $('#id').hide();
  $('#id').show();
```

Caso show/hide não funcione, você pode alterar as propriedades do CSS

```
 $("#id").css("display", "none");

 $("#id").css("display", "block");
```

}
})